# The format of the output files when using Sink Table

Tags: format, apache-flink

when I use TableAPI to create the sink table and submit the jobs. The files in S3 have the format like this

**part-2db289e0-e70a-48d4-ac11-3e75372f621d-1-179**

Therefore, I wonder what is the meaning of this format. To my knowledge, this format was followed this and I wonder if it is correct.

**part-<job_id>-<partition_id>-[numOfcommit]**

If it is correct, there is some questions that I would like to ask

I have set the commit time using this variable `sink.rolling-policy.check-interval` = `1min`. Therefore, does the numberOfCommit part of the output files means that every time that reach the commit time the file will closed and have that number? If so, what if the data is quite huge and needs more than the commit time, will they generate to another file? If so, what is the format of the files ?

One more question is that, how can we set the file size of the output since what the doc recommend is we adjust the commit time.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The details of how the underlying file system connector works is described in [the documentation for the DataStream FileSink connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#bucket-assignment).

The default naming scheme is

> In-progress / Pending: `part-<uid>-<partFileIndex>.inprogress.uid`
> Finished: `part-<uid>-<partFileIndex>`
>
> Uid is a random id assigned to a subtask of the sink when the subtask is instantiated. This uid is not fault-tolerant so it is regenerated when the subtask recovers from a failure.

If you use the DataStream API you can customize the bucket assigner and rolling policy, but with the SQL/Table API you are limited to the options described in its documentation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. However what I quite confused is that <partFileIndex> part. For example, the below partFileIndex is 1-179. Why it is always start at 1 but not 0. Moreover, what happens if the data arrives need more time to consume that the commit-time ?

Comment: This quite not have in the question but as it is stated in the doc that the parquet files is not support for Array type. Do you have any recommendation to convert from array to string ?

Comment: Moreover, I need more explain in the "SQL/Table API" part, you said that there is the limitation. However, I saw that in the documentation there is the option called 'sink.rolling-policy.file-size' which might relevant to the configuration of file size ? I don't know if I correct but thanks for helping me.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You don't have the option of implementing a custom rolling policy, but there are many options available for configuring the rolling policy, compaction, etc.

Comment: However, it is weird that although I set the size is small (1KB) for that option but it still contains the larger files more than that ? I wonder if the files prior the time commit beyond the file size setting options ?

Comment: And also I need help to understand further about 'partFileIndex'